# Submitting App when in app purchases are "Waiting for review" state

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have an ipad with 4 in app purchases. I have submitted my app for the first time and it got rejected saying "In app purchases were not submitted".

After seeing this message i submitted in app purchases and awaited for binary.

Now binary is ready but in app purchases are in "Waiting for review" state.

Can I submit my binary now?

Comment: you should also select your in app purchases in the app info page (toward the bottom) if you haven't already.

Comment: @MikeM Thanks for the reply. I submitted IAP through App details page some time back and now I am trying to submit binary but I donot see any IAP on App details page now.